# How to bind the "this" of a class constructor to an external object

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to use something similar to `Function.apply` for classes so that the `this` property of an executed constructor is an external object.

With a function I can simply use `apply`

```js
function Bar() {
  this.value = 'value'
}

const proxy = {}
Bar.apply(proxy, [])

console.log(proxy) // { value: 'value' }
```

However this does not, of course, work with classes

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.value = 'value'
  }
}

const proxy = {}
Foo.apply(proxy, [])

console.log(proxy)
```

Resulting in

```
Foo.apply(proxy, [])
    ^
TypeError: Class constructor Foo cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Is it possible to bind the `this` context of a class constructor to another object?

I don't have any legacy clients so I am able to use `Reflect.construct` (though I am not sure if it can solve the problem)

EDIT:

Alternatively, I can work with replacing `this` after construction. Is that possible?

```js
const foo = new Foo()
foo.bind(proxy)
```

Comment: Out of idle curiosity, why?

Comment: Haha fair enough. It's obviously a contrived example but the task I'm trying to solve is binding a class instance to an external `Proxy` so I can trap mutations at the point of construction.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's not possible. In order to support extending built-in classes (e.g. Array), the value of `this` must be created by (one of the) constructor, and hence there is no way to circumvent that.

Comment: Is it possible to replace `this` after construction? `const f = new Foo; f.bind(proxy)`?

Comment: @FelixKling I believe you remember correctly

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at [`[[Construct]]`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) of function objects (which is the internal method which will be executed when you use `new` or `Reflect.construct`), then you'll find this step in the specification:

```
Let thisArgument be ? OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(newTarget, "%Object.prototype%").
```

As there is no way to change this behavior, you cannot change what `thisArgument` is, it is always a regular object and cannot be a proxy. However, if you use `Reflect.construct`, you can influence the `newTarget`, and pass something else in than the regular constructor:

```
class Constructed {} // this is the function object that will be [[Construct]]ed
class Trapped {} // the "thisArgument" will inherit Trapped.prototype

Reflect.construct(Constructed, [], Trapped);
```

By injecting a proxy into `Trapped.prototype` you can have some reflection onto `this` inside a class constructor. An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64715857/5260024).

Answer (score -1):

You could create a `Proxy` that traps the `construct` and returns a proxified instance to trap the mutations:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.value = 'value';
  }
}

const ProxifiedFoo = new Proxy(Foo, {
  construct: (target, args) => {
    const instance = new target(...args);
    return new Proxy(instance, {
      set: (_, prop, value) => console.log(`Trying to set ${prop} to ${value}`)
    });
  }
});

const foo = new ProxifiedFoo;

console.log('Current value:', foo.value);

foo.value = 'otherValue';
```